# Really weird result with a database query from my app (sqlite database - detailed code inside)

Tags: android, database, filtering, android-sqlite

I am experiencing the weirdest problem now with my application while populating a listview with results from database.
So, I have an alertdialog in which I can **choose two criterias** to send to my database : a **category** product (restaurant, store, etc.) and a **payment option** (card/cash).

When the user choose something, it sets a String variable to a certain interval (**categoryInterval** and **paymentInterval**), this way :

**For category** (it's in a popup menu) :

```
case R.id.item11c:
                            filterTitle = "Bakery and Pastry Shops ";
                            categoryInterval = "('" + 86 + "','" + 87 + "')"; 
                            filterButton.setText("Bakery and Pastry shops");
                            return true;
```

**For payment options** (it's in a radio button) :

```
OnClickListener radiobutton_no_listener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        paymentInterval = "('" + "')";
    }
};

OnClickListener radiobutton_yes_listener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        paymentInterval = "('" + "visa" + "','" + "master" + "')";
    }
};
```

Then, when the user has made his choice, and clicks on the " OK " button of the alertdialog, there is a display method calling the query method **findFilterInTable()** (whose purpose is to find elements which have - in this case - one of their Category Column with the number 86 or 87 AND the Payment Column with "visa" or "master" inside) and displays the results in my listview :

```
public Cursor findFilterInTable(String categoryInterval,
        String paymentInterval) {
    String where = COL_CAT1 + " IN " + categoryInterval + " OR " + COL_CAT2
            + " IN " + categoryInterval + " OR " + COL_CAT3 + " IN "
            + categoryInterval + " AND " + COL_PAYMENT + " IN "
            + paymentInterval;

    Cursor c = myDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] { KEY_ROWID,
            COL_NAME, COL_STREET, COL_WEBSITE, COL_PAYMENT, COL_TELEPHONE,
            COL_PRICE, COL_REMARKS, COL_DATEFRIENDLY }, where, null, null,
            null, null);
    return c;
}
```

But it only works partially : it works perfectly well for the category part (COL_CAT1 in categoryInterval OR COL_CAT2 in ....) but for the payment part, I have a weird result. When I click this button (payment by card), it retrieves some results from the list compare to when I don't click but it retrieves things which are not at all relevant to the research. Whatever I write in my paymentInterval ("visa" or "master" as well as "okokininjfnsoe") what it seems to do is just to retrieve some elements with specific combinations of numbers IN the category part. For example, in this case, elements where CAT_3 = 87, which doesn't make sense.
So the value of my paymentInterval, in my findFilterInTable() method affects the results but doesn't even look in the appropriate column (COL_PAYMENT) but in the COL_CAT1, COL_CAT2, COL_CAT3 and for some reason, take off some results.

I am really upset with this and have no idea how to find a solution. I actually don't know how to solve a problem I don't understand and which doesn't make sense to me ! Thanks for reading.

Comment: why do you have paymentInterval = "('" + "')";

Comment: It's just because for the button "no credit card", it correspond to cash so basically every element from my database, so I let an empty string to retrieve every element from my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
String where = COL_CAT1 + " IN " + categoryInterval + " OR " + COL_CAT2
        + " IN " + categoryInterval + " OR " + COL_CAT3 + " IN "
        + categoryInterval + " AND " + COL_PAYMENT + " IN "
        + paymentInterval;
```

To

```
String where = "(" + COL_CAT1 + " IN " + categoryInterval + " OR " + COL_CAT2
        + " IN " + categoryInterval + " OR " + COL_CAT3 + " IN "
        + categoryInterval + ") AND " + COL_PAYMENT + " IN "
        + paymentInterval;
```

Comment: Perfect, that was it ! Thanks so much ! I just have one more question relative to the button with the empty interval. It happens to be wrong as when I click it, not every results is displayed so I guess it's filtering elements where the column is actually empty in the database (but sometimes it's not really empty, could be written N/A or cash or card or whatever).  Do you know what to write in this interval to make the query find EVERY elements of this column ?

Comment: You should have another function public Cursor findFilterInTable(String categoryInterval) and in your activity check if paymentInterval is empty then call this function. That way you do not have to have the line that struck me first as I comment above.

Comment: Wow there is no way ? I wanted to have one fonction called from my alertdialog OK button, because there will be many possible combinations : sometimes it's gonna be one category but no payment, sometimes payments and a price but no category, sometimes just a price and a category... I hoped I could use one big method which wouldn't always use every input, just those which are actually set to a value.

Comment: So far you have categoryInterval and paymentInterval and I guess priceInterval, how many more can you have?

Comment: Probably up to six, but the demand can evolve. I am running some test with the new code, there is something different with the paymentInterval : for example, when I put one name ("cash") in my interval, it will work and find elements with cash written. If I write "cash" + "N/A", it won't find anything, as if it was looking for "cash" AND "N/A" instead of "cash" OR "N/A". In my "paymentInterval for the button (no credit card, so everything) I wanted to write down everything i can find in this column ("cash", "visa", "N/A", " ", etc.) to display it all but then it's just not displaying anything.

Comment: Do you miss a comma in between "cash" and "N/A"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26989/discussion-between-hoan-nguyen-and-phalanx)

Comment: No I don't. And to give you another example, some elements of my database are having this description "visa|master|others|cash|debit|". When I write it like this in my paymentInterval, it works. But, if I just write "visa" (which is included in the "visa|master|others|cash|debit|") then... nothing shows up. So the query is really looking for exact same content to the letter, unlike my categoryInterval or my cuisineInterval which works the same way.